# duda con consulta sql

Tags: sql

buenas lo que pasa es que tengo un problema para consultar una tabla , tengo la típica tabla productos y categoría  en donde `id_categoria`  seria el atributo que relaciona las tablas

1. lo que no puedo hacer es traerme TODO de la tabla productos

no se si es por que las tablas estan relacionada

```
SELECT  *  FROM productos
```

y no me  funciona

pruebo hacer el `select` sin el atributo `id_categoria` y si funciona 
pero necesito la consulta con ese valor

muchas gracias por su colaboracion

Comment: Bienvenido  a SOes, Está un poco confusa tu pregunta pero creo haber entendido, lo que quieres es traer todo de la tabla productos incluida la categoría? ayudaría mucho si agregas la estructura de ambas tablas. Y aclara también a que te refieres con "no funciona" arroja error? o solo no trae resultados.

Comment: Lo que comentaas "lo que no puedo hacer es traerme TODO de la tabla productos" se puede deber a multiples causas, siempre e importante agregar más detalles como error mostrado. Como pruebas hacer el select  sin el atributo id_categoria ??? imagino atributo te refieres a un nombre de campo  id_categoria

Comment: Verifica el plan de ejecución, ya que podría ser que por las columnas que estas solicitando mostrar no exista un indice adecuado, esto pasa en tablas con muchos registros, o tuplas con con campos LOB

Comment: Puedes añadir la consulta con el atributo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aquí varias consultas con solo dos tablas donde tengo id_categoria en la tabla productos:

```
  *******************
  *productos        *
  *******************
  *id               *
  *nombre           *
  *descripcion      * 
  *id_categoria     *
  *******************

  *******************
  *categorias       *
  *******************
  *id               *
  *nombre           * 
  *descripcion      *
  *******************
```

traer todos los atributos de todos los registros de la tabla productos:

```
select * from productos
```

traer todos los productos relacionados con una determinada categoría:

```
select * from productos where id_categoria = 3
```

traer los nombres de los productos filtrados por el nombre de una categoría:

```
select nombre from productos where id_categoria in ( select id from categorias where nombre like %hogar% )
```

> puede que la que utilicé no sea la estructura de sus tablas, Si colocas tu estructura podríamos ayudarte de mejor manera. esperamos tus comentarios..

Answer (score 1):

Esto puede ocurrir si no usas alias en los `joins`. debido a que puede ser un problema devolver dos columnas con el mismo nombre.

```
SELECT A.CATEGOTYID, A.CATEGORYNAME, B.PRODUCTNAME
FROM CATEGORY AS A
INNER JOIN PRODUCT AS B
ON A.CATEGORYID = B.CATEGORYID
```

Así debería funcionar.